# Prove that a quotient group is cyclic

Tags: group-theory

So the full question is as follow:

> G is a finite group and F is a field. $\alpha : G\rightarrow F^\times$ homomorphism. $ Ker(\alpha)\le H \le G$. Prove that $H \triangleleft G$ and $ G/H $ is cyclic.

I have problem proving the second part of the question, proving that $ G/H $ is cyclic.

for the first part  $ H \triangleleft G $ I found 2 similar proofs:

Let us denote $ N = Ker(\alpha) $ , from the first Isomorphism theorem we know that $ G/N \cong K \subseteq F^\times $ because $ F^\times$ is abelian so is $K$ and so is $ G/N$.

(a) Since $ H/N \le G/N $ and since $ G/N $ is abelian then $ H/N \triangleleft G/N $ and from the third Isomorphism theorem we have $ H \triangleleft G $

(b) Since $G/N$ is abelian we have that the commutator group $G'\le N $ thus $G'\le H$ concluding that $H\triangleleft G$.

Any help with the **second** part would be appreciated as well as comments on my proof. thank you!

Comment: Hmm can you give an example for a non cyclic finite field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

For the second part it is enough to prove that finite subgroups of $F^{\times}$ are cyclic. Let $K\leq F^{\times}$ be a finite subgroup and let $n=|K|$. Then $g^n=1$ for any $g\in K$. In particular $K$ is the set of **all** $n$-th roots of unity. That's because over fields there are at most $n$ $n$-th roots of unity.

You can easily check that this set is a cyclic group with a primitive $n$-th root of unity as its generator.

Now back to your case, let $N=\ker(\alpha)$. By the third isomorphism theorem $G/H$ is isomorphic to $(G/N)/(H/N)$. Now $G/N$ is cyclic because by the first isomorphism theorem it is isomorphic to a finite subgroup of $F^{\times}$. Then $(G/N)/(H/N)$ is also cyclic as a quotient of a cyclic group.

Comment: why would this group be isomorphic to $G/H$

Comment: @KimSeel If $K=\mbox{im}(\alpha)\simeq G/\ker(\alpha)$ then $K$ is cyclic. By the third isomorphism theorem $G/H$ is isomorphic to a quotient $K/K'$. Quotients of cyclic groups are cyclic. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Watch out : freakish used a different notation : his $G$ is the isomorphic image of your $G/H$ in $F^{\times}$